# Class Diagram MVC pattern codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, design-patterns, model-view-controller, uml

[CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/) does not usually create a class for a "view". That means there is no method for the controller to call. How do I make a view class for this class diagram?
[image]

Comment: codeigniter that you have tagged points to php development framework. Here in the question, you have attached a class diagram. Are you looking for UML design diagrams issues ? or coding issues?

Comment: diagram. but i will implements with codeigniter,

Comment: I don't understand the English. Can you ask your question more clearly or ask a friend to help you?

Comment: sorry, not good in English. i had been edit my question.

Comment: This is an unusual request. Please give us some hints. Why do you need UML? Who will use the UML? For what purpose?

Comment: I following this tutorial [link]( http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm). I see a class diagram but implements  in java. In PHP Codeigniter not use method for file view. How to draw view in class diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how to create MVC class diagram for your codeigniter application ?

In codeigniter, a view is not a class, it's a file, called by a loader class,
so you can't create an MVC class diagram using your java article example.

The solution is to create only two classes (model and controller). To explain MVC in your application, you can use a collaboration or sequence diagram.

Here is an example about collaboration and sequence diagram for MVC:

[mvc-collaboration-sequence-diagram-example](http://www.slideshare.net/reggieniccolosantos/php-mvc-26944562)

Comment: ok, thanks. can you give me reference to design class diagram with model and controller (without class view )?, and whether i should use Entity-Control-Boundary pattern in this case?

Answer (score 0):

[phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/) will generate the class diagram. please check below the steps

**1) Install "Composer"**

Open your terminal and run the following four command
i)  php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
ii) php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
iii)    php composer-setup.php
iv) php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

**2) Create a folder** anywhere in you hard drive (e.g c:\phpdocumentor)
  and keep "composer.json" there

**3) install phpdocumentor**

Run c:\phpdocumentor>composer require "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor:2.*" 
// this command will install phpdocumentor to current working directory

**4) Generate class diagram**   // command line
Run phpdoc -d ./src -t ./docs/api

e.g. c:\phpdocumentor\vendor\bin>phpdoc -d C:/xampp/htdocs/test/application/controllers -t C:/xampp/htdocs/test/classdiagoutput
The basic usage of phpDocumentor is to provide an input location using the command line options (-d for a directory, -f for a file) and tell it to output your documentation to a folder of your liking (-t).
What the above example does is scan all files in the src directory and its subdirectories, perform an analysis and generate a website containing the documentation in the folder docs/api. If you want you can even omit the -t option, in which case the output will be written to a subfolder called output.

[It will generate result like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpLis.jpg)